# Error when using 'int' datatype even when number is not a decimal

Tags: c++, int

I understand the difference between int, float and double data types. But I have observed that sometimes when I use 'int' data type in a mathematical operation comprising of only integer values, it gives a result one less than the right answer. However, it's correct when I use float or double.

Take a look at the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int getno(int num)
{
    int x,i;
    float y=0;
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        x=num%10;
        y=y+(x*pow(10,i));
        num=num/10;
        cout<<x*pow(10,i)<<endl;
        cout<<y<<endl;
    }
    return y;
}

main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<getno(n);
}
```

if I change the datatype of y to int, it gives a wrong answer by one. i.e 12345 would result in 2344 instead of the required 2345. Why is that happening?

Comment: When performing int divisions, the answer is always truncated. (i.e. 5 / 3 == 1, not 2) Therefore, I don't see what's "wrong" here.

Comment: It's truncated, not rounded down.

Comment: @CarlNorum Sorry about my programming-english. Corrected now.

Comment: No problem, just clarifying.

Comment: Aki, could you for the sake of making it easier to see what's happening in your code provide a full output of your program, when using `y` as a float and when using it as an int?

Comment: In my compiler I get `2345` regardless of type of `y`.

Comment: I put your code over in codepad.org and after fixing a few warnings having to do with implicit type conversions, I am getting the correct answer for 12345 being 2345.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose "pow(10, i)" returns a bit less value than 10^i, let say 999.9999999 for i=3.

And afterwards it's truncated by float->int conversion into 99. As a result, we can loss 1 at every "y=.." operation.

Comment: "suppose"? Based on? Just guessing?

Comment: Func pow() usually use ln(x) and exp(x) under the hood (like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_via_logarithms)). These functions have data loss in last bits of double, and, as a result, we can get a bit less value than round/genuine integer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int getno(int num)
{
  int x,i;
  float y=0;
  for(i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    x=num%10;
    y=y+(x*pow(10.0f,(float)i));
    num=num/10;
    cout<<x*pow(10.0f,i)<<endl;
    cout<<y<<endl;
  }

  return (int)y;
}

int main(void)
{
  int n=12345;
//  cin>>n;
  cout<<getno(n);
  return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
5
5
40
45
300
345
2000
2345
2345
```

I just cleaned up the warnings about int to float conversion on your call to pow and explicitly convert your return type.